# How to make sure that a token exist?

Tags: tokens, nft, erc-721, require

I want to sell an NFT within my smart contract. But first, I want to check with a `require` statement if the token (NFT) exists or not before moving on to the next steps. I have tried   `require(ownerOf(tokenId), "Token doesn't exists.");` but Remix says:

```
from solidity:
TypeError: No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup.
   --> contracts/charMinter.sol:108:9:
    |
108 |         require(ownerOf(tokenId), "Token doesn't exists.");
    |         ^^^^^^^
Note: Candidate: function require(bool)
Note: Candidate: function require(bool, string memory)
```

I also tried `require(tokenURI(tokenId), "Token doesn't exists.");` but I get the same error as above. Is there a way to check if a token exists or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_exists(uint tokenId)` function inheritanced from ERC721 smart contract.

You must to change your original condition like this:

```
require(_exists(tokenId), "Token doesn't exists.");
```

You can read more about this function [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721-_exists-uint256-).

Example of smart contract that use this function:

```
// SDPX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Test is ERC721 {

    constructor() ERC721("TestToken", "TT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 0);
    }

    function checkIfTokenExist(uint _tokenId) external view returns(address) {
        require(_exists(_tokenId), "Error!");
        return ownerOf(_tokenId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not valid for OpenZeppelin 5.x versions. Can you add this information as well please? 5.x release notes states that: The `_exists` function was removed. Calls to this function can be replaced by `_ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0)`

Comment: Release notes: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/releases/tag/v5.0.0